# Asymptotic expansion of a special integral

Tags: analysis, computational-mathematics

I need an asymptotic expansion of J(n)

$J(n)=\frac {2} {\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/n} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac {\sin kx} {\sin x} dx$, $n=2,3,4,\dots$

Can anybody help to find the asymptotic analytically or at least via numirical calculation please?
Also, I wonder if there is a graphical interpretation of the result exists?
Best to my knowledge the integral is not very simple to get an answer.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: is the sine in the denominator considered under product, i.e is it effectively $$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n\sin kx}{\left(\sin x\right)^n}$$?

Comment: @Valentin It seems so.

Comment: @Valentin yes, you are right, the same you wrote.

Comment: Not fit for an answer, but maybe this argument will suggest the solution path. Consider a similar integral:
$$I=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{n}} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos kx}{\cos x}dx$$
 $$\cos x=t$$
 $$dx=-\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$$
 $$I=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{1}^{\cos\frac{\pi}{n}} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{T_k(t)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$
Where $T_k$ are [Chebyshev Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html). Now
$$T_{k}\left(x\right)=2^{k-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left\{ x-\cos\left[\frac{\left(2k-1\right)\pi}{2n}\right]\right\}$$. etc

Comment: @Valentin Do you mean to wrap the integral around circles of radius 2n like for Chebyshev Polynomials by Michael Trott you mentioned at Mathworld?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got:

For $x\in [0,\pi/n]$, we have $\sin(x)=x(1+O(1/n^2))$.  Similarly, we have $\sin^n(x)=x^n(1+O(1/n))$.  Let us write $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.  We have $|f(x)|\leq 1$, but for any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $f(x)\geq 1-\epsilon$ for $x\in [0,\delta]$

Then, for $x\in[0,\pi/n]$:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sin(x)}=n!(1+O(1/n))\prod_{k=1}^n f(kx)
$$

Now, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
J(n)&=&\frac{2}{\pi}n!(1+O(1/n))\int_0^{\pi/n}\prod_{k=1}^n f(kx)\,dx\\
&\geq&n!(1+O(1/n))\int_0^{\delta/n}(1-\epsilon)^n\,dx\\
&\geq&\frac{2}{\pi}(n-1)!(\delta+O(1/n))(1-\epsilon)^n
\end{eqnarray*}

Similarly, we have
$$
J(n)\leq 2(n-1)!(1+O(1/n))
$$

We can combine these two estimates to get
$$
J(n)=(n-1)!(1+o(1))^n
$$

Of course, $(n-1)!=n!(1+o(1))^n$, so we can write
$$
J(n)=n!(1+o(1))^n
$$
It might be useful to use Stirling's formula to get
$$
J(n)=\left(\frac{n}{e}(1+o(1))\right)^n
$$

Using Mathematic, I computed $\left(\frac{J(500)}{499!}\right)^{1/500}=.99554\ldots$

Comment: Thank you, I have $J_1(n)=\frac {n!} {\sqrt{\pi A}}$, $A=n(n-1)(2n+5)/36$, so my calculation is slightly different: .98324... Generally I need an asymptotic expansion of the integral. It would be nice to represent it via special functions.